# Change admin routers after supee 6788

Tags: adminhtml, supee-6788

I have a module where the admin does not work:

I had it like this:

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <custommenu>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Custommenu</module>
                    <frontName>custommenu</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommenu>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

I've changed it to this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <custommenu after="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Custommenu_Adminhtml</custommenu>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>        
</admin>
```

But I get frontend 404's. 
What else should I change?

Thanks!

Comment: Can  please tell me,your controller path?

Comment: @AmitBera Company_Custommenu_Adminhtml_ItemsController and Company_Custommenu_Adminhtml_LinksController is this what you're asking?

Comment: i asking path location not class name

Comment: @AmitBera Company/Custommenu/controllers/Adminhtml/ItemsController.php is the path

Comment: You should also check `getUrl()` and `_redirect()` function calls for the right routing paths as well as entries in `system.xml` which call your controller(s).